If humans had tails, could they use them to hang from things?
If humans had prehensile tails extending from the spine, similar in proportion to monkeys, would they be able to hang from a tree branch with it? Further, how heavy of an object could we expect a tailed-human to lift? Could they lift up say, a few kg exercise weight?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comparing Uhura's Song from Star Trek, with "oversized cats" with tails, they could hang by the tail. Yet, VTC story-based, as if you'd attach a literal trunk instead of a tail, it might have been used for more than just climbing trees.

@Vesper the question is asking about the general range of capabilities that a human-scaled prehensile tail might have in terms of supporting the posessor and other objects - this is in no way story-based.  However, Rocky, it's worth noting that there have both been previous questions on this subject that this is close to being a duplicate of https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/212973/reality-check-strong-but-prehensile-tail?rq=1 and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/87459/how-could-you-make-a-cats-tail-prehensile-enough-to-use-weapons

@KerrAvon2055 I looked at them, I feel like I never quite saw a definitive yes or no answer on them.

These tails can do whatever they're evolved to do... aid balance... pick up stuff... allow its bearer to hang from it... look like the devil's tail... have a rattle on the end... it's up to you which of the things that tails have evolved to do that your alternate humans can do with theirs.

@Rocky becasue it all depends on the anatomy of the tail, you could build a tail that would work and you could build a tail that won't. it all depends on how you build your fictional tail.

Yes, they could swing by their tails, no problem

This is actually a very easy to answer speculative anatomy & physiology question. VTR.

@elemtilas yeah, no idea why it was closed, vtr as well

Hi rocky. I'll VTR as well, but for future reference, you are allowed to ask one and only one question. You're asking two. We're (usually) lenient with new users, but please keep this in mind for future questions. Thanks!

@jbh They’re essentially the same question rephrased. How much weight could the tail support us the superset of whether it is sufficient to support the human’s weight. I would be forgiving of this phrasing.

@SRM We're not because no one (including yourself) can read the OP's mind. You're making an assumption they're basically the same. Better to help educate new users than to excuse bad behavior that will only cause problems later. (Keep in mind I did not vote to close. I only explained a rule.)

You hit a weird philosophical/ evolutionary question. Ostensibly since we originally seem to have come from earlier iterations of primate with tails ( https://www.visualcapitalist.com/path-of-human-evolution/ ), the short answer is 'no', since we obviously didn't use them enough to be an evolutionarily beneficial (enough) trait to keep. We would most likely lose them again unless our lifestyles were so drastically different from a mobility standpoint to warrant keeping them. Or, you know, we just selected ourselves into keeping them.
To then take the other perspective if you copied+pasted tails onto modern humans, you get the more interesting questions answered. As for how much we would use them and by how much.. first off, I'm not a muscu-sceletal doctor but I would look into just how current primates use their tails, and with what degree of control and dexterity they have. It's possible in this universe that our tails would have evolved to be more dexterous than others to where fine motor control is easier. As for strength, I would argue in any case the answer to lifting capacity would be a 'fair amount'. Depending on tail length and manner of grip, a tail could probably manage a lot. Consider how strong fingers are; while a gross oversimplification, what are fingers functionally but simplified short tails? Point being with the right muscle structure could probably manage a fair amount. Hanging might be one of those things that only some people are capable of doing, requiring much training to achieve. For hard numbers I would consult whoever analyzes dinosaur bones to determine their capabilities; they would know how to do that math.

OTHO we lost our tails long before we became bipedals. This suggests the "prehensile" tail (coiling tail, rather) was mainly a balancer for branch crawling and more of a backup if balancing failed. The main cost from becoming bipedal is we're handicapped at the balancing beam w/resp to apes: raised CoM, non-prehensile feet and smaller area of sustentation.

Given our modern posture and frequency of sitting, I’d love to jump ahead generations to see if we lose legs entirely!

Humans are too big
The largest species of monkey that hangs from its tail is the Ateles Geoffroyi Spider Monkey and it only weighs about 9kg(20lb).  Larger monkeys like Howler monkeys which average 12kg(28lb) for females or 28kg(62lb) for males can use their tails to help support their weight, but can not hang by them exclusively. Human are significantly heavier even than howler monkeys.
It all comes down to the good old square-cube rule. In order to support our own weight, the joints in a human spine have had to evolve deeper facets, but this significantly reduces the flexibility of the spine so if you were to give a human a tail, it would either be too inflexible for effective gripping, or so flexible that the joints would easily become dislocated under our own weight leading to injuries.
Although hands seem like they should be more prone to dislocation, they are not because when you hold yourself up by a hand, the actual tension in not on the joints pulling apart, but on the ligaments that attach along the length of your forearm which compress your finger joints together when they are under strain.  Because your finger joints do not directly support one another in sequence like tail bones do, they are not prone to the same issues.  Instead, you only need to worry about each segment of your arm which is much bigger than a tail segment. So, they are supported by much larger muscle and ligament groups to help keep everything held together.

It depends on the muscular/tendon/ligament and to a lesser extent on the skeletal development of that tail.
Consider a small monkey with a thin tail: It probably can use the tail to hang from a tree.
Consider a bigger monkey with a tail: It probably can't use it for that purpose or only close to the body not on the far end.
Stability-wise the human tail would have to be close to a (thin/underdeveloped) arm in terms of supporting the body weight hanging (straight downwards) on it. Also this would probably only be possible close to the body, not on the far end.
In terms of lifting capacity you need to consider the angle and lever that this tail has. This fifth limb would have a near perpendicular angle to the body, which is the worst case that you can have in order to lift and hold things - and it only worsens with length of the tail.
Imagine this: You can easily hang on one arm from a tree and hold your full body weight probably without problems for some time (minutes). But holding a weight on your fully streched out arm (also being perpendicular to your body) will bring you to limits very quickly (maybe a tenth of your body weight for some seconds max if you are training this like an extreme bodybuilder).
The tail would have similar limits to that, given it is strong enough to hold the hanging body weight: Lifting a few kilos will work if the tail can hold firm to the weight close(est) to the body (making it necessary using a squatting-to-stand move probably to lift things from the ground), but it will be near impossible to lift (heavier) things from the ground on the far end.
