# How could sapient dogs develop 17-century technology without having hands?

Tags: society, technology, warfare, dogs

In my world, dog-like creatures gradually developed a 17-century civilization over time. It is believed that a now extinct species modified the dogs to have human-like intelligence. The dogs have found remnants of tech from the extinct species, but have no way of understanding or using it.

The dog's body length is on average 53-66 cm

The standing height is 46-56 cm

Lifespan is 40-50 years (Without medicine)

They walk on 4 legs like dogs normally do

They have adapted to living in cold areas

The question:

How could sapient dogs develop 17-century technology without having hands?

Comment: For future reference, we'd prefer it if you edit the [old question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/close/88365) and un-delete it rather than making a new one.

Comment: Related: [sapient cats etc.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/72089/castles-weapons-and-war-tactics-for-sapient-cats) and [sapient with split prehensile tail](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/141916/reality-check-plausibility-of-a-new-kind-of-sentient-alien-race-split-prehensi).

Comment: We have a strict one question per post policy. You're asking at least 5 questions. Can you [edit] your post to ask one and only one question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Pelinore Good point. I missed that. But the issue is the same. *They can't* because without modification that allows them to manipulate the world around them they can't use the vast majority of technology at any time period. Even your answer isn't realistic. No, one needn't understand it to use it. But if a narrow, cylindrical handle must be twisted to use it (like the handle on a camera tripod to tighten it), then paws won't work no matter how intelligent the dogs are.

Comment: @JBH agreed, which is why I concentrated on giving them hands:) did you miss that that was the main point of my answer? the bit you mention was merely the preamble setting it up:)

Answer (score 3):

First an observation.

**Technology is not the same thing as societal structures and norms**

Second a frame challenge.

**Technology does not need to be understood to be used**

Ignorance of the inner workings of a combustion engine, cranks, pistons and gears won't hinder you in any way when it comes to using a car .. in fact the more advanced the technology most often the less you need to understand it to make use of it .. ask yourself how much you understand about the technology and science that your iphone is built on, if your being honest then the answer is going to be practically nothing, unless you've several degrees in multiple disciplines.

Robot servants that respond to ordinary spoken instructions, if we had them, would perhaps be the ultimate expression of this reality about technology.

..

So, they're genetically altered by 'a now extinct species'?

Presumably said species had a society and it's infrastructure the dogs simply 'inherited', the idea has already been done in 'City' by Clifford Simak, iirc in his story there were humanoid robots left over from the humans who 'uplifted' them, which gets around any issues there may be with them not having hands, the old robots can of course make new ones.

Whatever leftover technology and infrastructure they may have at their disposal they'll still develop their own society.

So a seventeenth century style society with some twenty second century technology at its disposal.

Which though not mutually exclusive elements will still make for an interesting dichotomy of sorts.

Your dogs can simply have no interest or real understanding of anything beyond any seventeenth century tech and have only kept and used the robots for their hands telling them to make more of themselves when they need them, which may mean that somewhere there are leftover automated factories and infrastructure they ignore to extract and process materials for their construction.

> The robots can be governed by whatever protocols you want or need to avoid their misuse in any way that disrupts your intended story (an Asimov three laws deal, though you don't have to use his laws of course) and as the dogs simply don't understand the technology they can't redesign or reprogram those factory standard settings.

So in summation.

Option one.

**Robot servants with hands**

Relics left over from the society that genetically engineered your dogs that are able to repair each other and build more of themselves as needed.

..

Option two.

**Service animals**

Your dogs long ago domesticated something like a capuchin monkey as a common household pet and service animal, which also gives them access to hands other than the ones they don't possess.

You could mix and match both of course.

Answer (score 1):

Dogs use their mouths and paws as hands. I give my dogs snack "sticks" wrapped in bacon; they all lie down, hold the stick between their paws, and use their mouth to carefully peel off the bacon to eat it first. The stick itself is crunchy but edible; they do the same thing: clamp it in their front paws and use their molars to bite pieces off.

This is not just one dog, but many dogs. Just like an elephant can learn to use its trunk to hold a paintbrush and use it, or to wield a hammer, a dog with human intelligence and ingenuity would devise tools it can wield with its mouth or lips (which, as you've seen when they bare their teeth, are movable).

It would develop "lying down" desks (think of an inclined plane) to keep it's rear end near the ground but its chest raised but supported, so its arms and paws are free to move, and it can bend its head to work on things on the bench. For finer work, it would invent tools it can operate with it's mouth that can move or cut more finely; just like we invented chisels and needles and writing instruments that work more finely than our fingers and nails. Then tools are used to create even finer tools, lenses, microscopes, telescopes. Tool making is a bootstrap function, we began with sticks and stones, shells and rocks. Dogs would do the same.

The important thing in human development was never **hands**, it was abstract intelligence. Elephants and dolphins both invent and use tools without any hands, crows shape tools shaped like saws out of stiff leaves, cutting them with their beaks. The dolphins tear out and shape sponges to use like a glove on their snout so they can stir up dirt to make crustaceans jump, for a treat. They'll carry these gloves a long distance to use them.

One of my dogs understood trade! If I were eating a snack, she would bring me one of her toys, drop it at my feet, and look up at me to see if I'd take the trade. (Of course I did.)

Humans with just arms and no hands would figure out how to survive and make tools they could use with their arms and feet; they wouldn't just lay down and die. The fine control of fingers is great, but in the end our tools make that control even finer, even tens of thousands of times finer. It is a compounding process, every time we make a tool (like a lever) that can convert a large action into a more forceful small action, we can use that to make more tools that use that small action to make an even smaller action.

Thinking in that direction, the tools of dogs could be lever controlled: A pivot well off center, so we have a long "paw arm" and a small "action" arm. The dog moves the paw arm five inches, and the action arm moves 5/16ths of an inch. Stuff like that.

Big machines with large movements to make small devices with small units. The first "machines" we developed were likely levers and fulcrums; dogs could certainly manage that, too, using their mouths and paws.